# How to get the assembly name and class name with full namespace of a given class in the solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm working with WPF and often have the need to get the namespace and assembly name of a given class. But I don't know how to do this.

So, how can we get the names when browsing the classes in the Solution Explorer or/and when editing the class's codes? Please help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the Visual Studio *Immediate Window* as a quick way to obtain the assembly qualified name for one of the solution projects.

IIRC, these steps should work:

1. Open the file of a class contained in the project for which you want to obtain assembly name;
2. Set that project as the startup project for the solution;
3. Open the *Immediate Window*, default C# environment shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>;
4. In the Immediate Window type `typeof(ClassNameOfStep1).AssemblyQualifiedName` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The *Immediate Window* depends on Design-Time Expression Evaluation
 which in turns depends of Visual Studio Hosting Process so you need to have it enabled, which by default already is.

Also, I did some quick tests and the Name of the class was sufficient in all cases except when I tried it on VS 2008, which required me to provide the `FullName` of the type. So if `Name` results in error use the `Name` qualified with the namespace.

Comment: I tried, but got error "The type or namespace name 'MyClass' is not valid in this scope"

Comment: @Nam Gi VU, instead of `MyClass` try to use `MyNamespace.MyClass`.

Comment: @Angelo: I put in the full namespace of the class but doesn't work either. I got "'CCC' does not exist in the namespace 'A.BB'" when I pass in typeof(A.BB.CCC.DDDD).AssemblyQualifiedName :)

Comment: @Nam Gi VU Make sure your application is running

Comment: @Nam Gi Vu, I updated my answer with a missing step (2). Check if that solves the error. It should resolve it, but even if it does this new step kind of removes the simplicity of the solution.

Comment: @Angelo: I got it now. Thanks to a colleague of mine idea: need to run the solution and while the application is running, proceed your suggestion steps above. Thank you Angelo.

Comment: Don't need to run guys. Just do step 2 (set the start-up project).

Answer (score 6):

These should give you what you're after:

```
var assemblyName = typeof(ClassNameGoesHere).AssemblyQualifiedName;
var namespaceOfClass = typeof(ClassNameGoesHere).Namespace;
```

I see you've just added a note to your question regarding "when browsing the classes in the Solution Explorer", the simple answer is that as far as I know, you can't because that's not what Solution Explorer is for (it's there for browsing the files in a solution, not what's contained inside them) and also because:

1. One file can contain multiple
   classes
2. All files in one project
   will, generally, always compile down
   to a single assembly, making it
   redundant to display that name for
   each file.

You may want to see if the "Class View" gives you what you want, but, I suspect it won't.

Comment: Hi Rob,
I'm looking for a no-coding solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU, I've added an update to take into account your addition to the question regarding Solution Explorer.

Comment: I see. I've tried in the Class View but no help there. I've updated to add the case: when editing the class's codes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use F# interative, just open the window (View -> Other Windows -> F# Interactive) and try the following:

```
> typedefof<System.Uri>.Assembly.FullName;;
    val it : string =
      "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

There are a few assemblies referenced automatically like System. If you need to get the name from another assembly, you'll need to add the reference first (like the service model for example).

```
> #r "System.ServiceModel.dll";;

--> Referenced 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.ServiceModel.dll'

> typedefof<System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject>.Assembly.FullName;;
val it : string =
  "System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
```

F# interative is part of Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score -4):

You need `Object Browser`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

There you'll see all meta information of types.

Comment: Can you explain more about which meta information I should look for?