# Problem accessing namespace in Visual Studio 2010 add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, add-in

I've been tasked with turning a preexisting project into an add-in. The current project is a class library. In the add-in, I added the CL project as a reference. In the add-in's Connect class' Exec method, I tried adding the following code to open the entry point for the CL:

```
var form = new CLNameSpace.MainForm();
form.Show();
```

Where CLNameSpace (renamed for this article) is the namespace being referenced from the CL project. It is also in the `using` block at the top of the code. I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193255/how-to-get-the-assembly-name-and-class-name-with-full-namespace-of-a-given-class/3194121#3194121)'s method to get the fully qualified name and it is correct. I do not get any build or run-time errors but something is wrong. Using the Immediate Window to instantiate the two lines above by hand, I get the following error message:

> The type or namespace name 'CLNameSpace' is not valid in this scope

How do I get around this namespace visibility issue? I wonder if it's some kind of configuration in CLNameSpace (if that's even possible.)

Comment: How did you import the namespace?

Comment: @0xA3 Right-clicked the project in the Solution Manager, clicked Add Reference, and selected the project using CLNameSpace. Since this was yielding a problem, I tried adding a reference to the output DLL of that project. Intellisense picks up everything inside that namespace now but I'm still getting the invalid namespace error.

Comment: Sorry, but I meant the actual `using` statement. Can you show your code?

Comment: @0xA3 I'm wondering if it makes a difference that CLNameSpace is would more accurately be represented as A.B.CLNameSpace - It's on the bottom tier of that.

`using System;
using Extensibility;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars;
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using A.B.CLNameSpace;`

Comment: So then just remove the `CLNameSpace` part when you create the instance of your form: `var form = new MainForm();`

Comment: I get the following error: `The type or namespace name 'MainForm' is not valid in this scope`

Comment: Can you please post a full sample that produces this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably would have to do something like this:

```
var form = new CLNameSpace.MainForm();
form.Show();
```

Note that [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx) would start a standard application message loop - but your main application already has a message loop so trying to start another message loop will not produce any meaningful result.

Comment: First, you're correct. I tried a test in another solution and that worked. I put in a breakpoint and used the Immediate window to declare it by hand - it's telling me "The type or namespace name 'CLNameSpace' is not valid in this scope." I have it referenced properly and I have a `using CLNameSpace;` statement in that block of the code.