# How to find out relative path of image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, imagesource

In a legacy project there are absolute path to the images,
for example:

```
C:/projects/LegacyProject/Project/Client/UserInterface/Images/arrow.png
```

Now I want to use relative path, so that every developer can use that
project, no matter where he has his copy of the sourcecode.

Is there an easy way to find out the (Resource) relative path?
How can I use it then?

At the moment I have for example:

```
<Image Source="C:/projects/LegacyProject/Project/Client/UserInterface/Images/arrow.png" Stretch="Fill" />
```

What I want is something like:

```
<Image Source="arrow.png" Stretch="Fill" />
```

Tried around with

```
<Image Source="pack:,,, arrow.png" Stretch="Fill" />
<Image Source="/WPF1;arrow.png"></Image>
```

and similar things

Comment: Not sure about your context but I think `~` does equate to the application root. You shoul be able to do `<Image Source="~/Images/arrow.png" Stretch="Fill" />` unless off course after the root the `UserInterface` or `Client/UserInterface` are folders after the root. then you need to add them too, i.e: `<Image Source="~/Client/UserInterface/Images/arrow.png" Stretch="Fill" />`

Comment: How can I say what the application root is? There is more than one namespace in the project, perhaps thats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add image using `Source` property of the `Image` control by clicking

[image]

then the path will be something like this:

```
/[project name];component/[folder name: e.g. Images]/[file name]
```

Comment: This one works, after finding out the correct project name as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193255/how-to-get-the-assembly-name-and-class-name-with-full-namespace-of-a-given-class ... and of course massive rebuilding ;)

Answer (score 4):

Put the image files into a folder (named let's say `Images`) in your Visual Studio project and set their [build action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) to `Resource`.

Now you can simply use them in XAML like this:

```
<Image Source="Images/arrow.png" ... />
```

In code-behind you would have to write

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/arrow.png");
image.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

Comment: Thank you! Have re-included the images in the project, the build action is "Resource", they are in a folder "images" and I get a XAML Parse exception "'Failed to create a 'ImageSource' from the text 'Images/arrow.png'". I need it in XAML, not the code behind.

Comment: Are the images in another assembly that is referenced from you project?

Comment: No, it is all in one assembly

Comment: Strange, it should simply work like that. Does it work to create a `BitmapImage` in code as shown? Just to make sure that the file is not somehow corrupted. Which .Net version is it?

Comment: .NET 4.0, have to try out the BitmapImage part.

Comment: The solution suggested by Hossein works well, will use that one. But I'm also curious why your solution does not work. Will have to watch later. Thank you!